# sitecore installation wizard could not install some content

Tags: solr, sitecore

I would like to ask you if someone has similar problem. I am using Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 151021) with Solr. I need to add some items from prod to my local sitecore instance. When I create package and tried to install specific content I get exception null reference exception. It doesnt depend on the content. I tried to used package designer with varios content and always I get this exception.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the index config files on your local instance? This error can happen when something is not ok there, e.g. an unavailable rootitem..

Comment: First thing to check is if you have the templates, layouts, etc for the items that you are restoring in your loca.

Comment: You definitely have some problem with indexes. Try to disable indexes, install package and then enable them. However you should still find the root of indexes problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate: Make sure that all of the supporting items that each item in the package require are in place in the destination before trying to install them through a package.

Normally, separate packages are created for Templates, Layouts and Content and installed in that order to avoid missing dependencies.

You can also look into disabling Index builds during package installation. I have a module out there that does this:
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Detailed_Package_Installer.aspx